# Text as a price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a recent Woocommerce installation and i'm trying to create a way when there is no price in the backend, Woocommerce automatically makes the price "Prijs op aanvraag" But when using the following code in my function.php:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'custom_call_for_price');

function custom_call_for_price() {
 return 'Prijs op aanvraag';
}
```

But now i can't add it to my cart anymore? Can anyone give me a idea or plugin how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
   function custom_woocommerce_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){
        if($product->get_price() == '')
            $purchasable = true;
        return $purchasable;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'custom_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```

Above code will add `Add to cart` button.

**NOTE** : It will consider **0.00** as a price.

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks!